# PhpStorm: excluding drives from "open file or project" dialog

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, power-saving

I'm having several external USB drives connected to my PC (which are not required for my work with PhpStorm) and I'm wondering: is it possible to exclude drives from the "open file or project" dialog?

The problem is, these drives are going into power saving mode (by switching off) after a certain amount of time; so when opening the dialog, it almost takes a minutes before I can select a project as the system needs to power them up first.

Any Idea?

Comment: *"I'm wondering: is it possible to exclude drives from the "open file or project" dialog?"* There are no such options. What OS & IDE version do you use? Some workarounds are possible though.

Comment: Do you have an external hard drive or a USB Stick? Do they really consume that much power if turned ON?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to exclude a drive from *File | Open*. The new file chooser, however, doesn't list drives, so it might be a solution. Try enabling it at *Help | Find Action | Registry | ide.ui.new.file.chooser*.